# how to get method parameter name of proxy class in Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to get method parameter name of proxy class in Spring AOP. My code is:

```
@Around("writeLog()")
    public Object doBefore(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
        String[] paramNames = signature.getParameterNames();
    }
```

However, the variable `paramNames` always is `null`.

Version info:
- spring-boot: 2.0.7.RELEASE
- cglib: 3.2.9

So is there any method to solve the problem, thanks?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Does the method `writeLog` have defined parameters?

Comment: this is my method `writeLog()`:

```
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.sankuai.nebula.controller..*.*(..))")
    public void writeLog() {

    }
```

Comment: Could you please update the question with a Controller class method that will be adviced ?